# RPi used as wakeup-light, bashscript+CEC+Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, linux

I've a vision about using my RPi as a wake up light device along with my TV. 
The way it "should" work in my head is that I have it constantly on, checking the time. At a certain time it sends a CEC wake up command to the TV it's connected to. Immediately afterwards it begins to slowly brighten to an almost white light using a movie file i have already created.

Sounds not to hard to do maybe but the RPi is my first Linux-based experience and I'm still learning. So help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you thought about having a series of movie files (or even a gif, jpg png) and swapping that out as time progresses? Or scrapping the need for the TV and using led(s) connected to the GPIO pins?

Comment: @SteveRobillard
Well, i already have a TV and the moviefile is already created. All i need is a command to start the playback of the file for it to dim the TV the way i want. but ofcourse, a slideshow of jpgs would do too.
The leds will be a later part in my wake up project, just beginning to play around with home automation and arduinos for the leds.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are not very familiar with Linux or programming, are you? So I try to give you some hints where to start:

1. Linux:
   You usually do not want to check the time constantly (this is called [Busy Waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). Instead you could use [Cron Jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to start a program at a specific time.
2. Programming:
   Python is a suitable scripting language which should satisfy any of your needs - i even found a [cec library](https://github.com/trainman419/python-cec). Somehow I do think that enabling your TV to play a movie is an overkill. You could directly connect some LEDs to your RaspberryPi via its GPIOs. Have a look at [this resource](http://lwk.mjhosting.co.uk/?p=343).